# What are the best updated Ruby on Rails books and resources?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What are the best updated Ruby on Rails books and resources? I am working on a web app to be built using the RoR framework and I need to learn everything I can, seriously!

Answer (score 2):

[Agile Web Development with Rails (4th edition)](http://pragprog.com/titles/rails4/agile-web-development-with-rails) is one of the best beginners book available.

From the introduction:

> This book is for programmers looking
>   to build and deploy web-based
>   applications. This includes
>   application programmers who are new to
>   Rails (and perhaps even new to Ruby)
>   and ones who are familiar with the
>   basics but want a more in-depth
>   understanding of Rails.

If you're also new to Ruby I strongly recommend [Ruby Koans](http://rubykoans.com/).

Also:

- [Ruby on Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/) (The
  official guide)
- [Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/)
  (Screencasts)
- [ASCIIcasts](http://asciicasts.com/)
  (railscasts text version)

Comment: +1 for the guide (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/) . I have learned nearly everything I need to know about rails from the guide (and my awesome co-workers).

Comment: Me too. Best official programming guide I've ever seen.

Answer (score 1):

[Rails for zombies](http://railsforzombies.org/) is quite good for starters.

Answer (score 1):

To add to all of the above, another good book after you get through those resources is [Rails Antipatterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321604814). While I do not suggest this book for a beginner as learning the basics of Rails is overwhelming enough, once you get past that stage then this book will be the logical next step in learning how to refactor your code better.

Answer (score 0):

[Code School](http://www.codeschool.com/) has a video course online that includes interactive problems. I went through their more advanced Rails course and liked it. I'd definitely recommend their basic (and free) course, [Rails for Zombies](http://www.codeschool.com/courses/rails-for-zombies)